# Getting weights as percentages from edges

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two node types "Person" and "Company". There is also a relationship called "Shareholder", which can be from Person to Company or Company to Company (as companies can also hold shares in other companies). The Shareholder relationship has three properties "shareholding_start_date", "shareholding_end_date", "number_of_shares".

I want to be able to query a Company (call it **c**) by name, as well as provide a date (e.g. '2021-07-23'), and the query should return all Person/Company nodes that are shareholders of **c** at the date '2021-07-23' (i.e. shareholding_start_date < 2021-07-23 < shareholding_end_date). I also want to calculate the percentage based on 'number_of_shares'.

As an example, let's say there is a company called XYZ, and I want to know all it's shareholders on 2022-03-15. Suppose ABC has three shareholders ABC, DEF, GHI on this day (these can be either Person or Company nodes). ABC holds 30 shares, DEF holds 50 shares, GHI holds 120 shares.

The query should be something like this (obviously this is not cypher, but I'm unable to express it in any other way!):

```
Company.name = "XYZ"
and Shareholder.shareholding_start_date <= 2022-03-15
and SHareholder.shareholding_end_date >= 2022-03-15
```

Returns something like:

```
ABC 15%, DEF 25%, GHI 60%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MATCH (c:Company {name:"ABC"})<-[r:Shareholder]-(s)
WHERE r.shareholding_start_date <= Date("2022-03-15") 
   AND r.shareholding_end_date >= DATE("2022-03-15")
WITH c, 
collect(s) as shareholders, 
collect(r) as rels, 
sum(r.number_of_shares) AS totalShares
UNWIND range(0, size(rels) - 1) AS i
RETURN shareholders[i].name AS shareholder, 
100.0 * rels[i].numberOfShares/totalShares as percentTotalShares
```

For more examples of percent of total in Neo4j, see this blog post. https://medium.com/neo4j/kickstart-your-transition-from-sql-analytic-and-window-functions-to-neo4j-987d67f7fdb4

To show shareholders of shareholders to an arbitrary distance from your target company as requested in the comment, you might use this approach.

```
MATCH p=(c:Company {name:"ABC"})<-[r:Shareholder*1..3]-(holder)
WHERE all(holding IN relationships(p) WHERE holding.shareholding_start_date <= Date('2022-03-15') <= holding.shareholding_end_date) 
WITH 
   length(p) - 1 AS distanceToTargetCompany, 
   nodes(p)[-2].name AS companyName,
   holder, 
   relationships(p)[-1].number_of_shares AS number_of_shares
WITH 
   distanceToTargetCompany,
   companyName,
   collect(DISTINCT {shareHolder: holder.name, numberOfShares: number_of_shares}) as shareHolders
WITH 
   distanceToTargetCompany, 
   companyName, 
   shareHolders,
   reduce(acc=0, company in shareHolders | acc + company['numberOfShares']) AS totalShares
RETURN 
   distanceToTargetCompany, 
   companyName, 
   reduce(acc=[], company in shareHolders | acc + company{.*, percentTotal:100.0 * company['numberOfShares']/totalShares}) AS shareHolders
ORDER BY distanceToTargetCompany, companyName
```

Comment: thank you for your response! I was wondering if you knew whether this code could be extended to also show shareholders of the shareholders? Perhaps in a recursive manner?

Comment: I edited my answer to add shareholders of shareholders. It might not be the output format you are looking for, but it's tricky to format the output when you search to an arbitrary depth.

Comment: thanks very much Nathan! Do you know if it's possible to set the shareholder percentage as a attribute on the relationship instead of returning it? The shareholder relationship has an attribute called holding_percentage by default set to 0. Could we update this in the query above?